# Setting default paper size in PageSetupDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying this code:

```
PageSetupDialog pageSetupDialog = new PageSetupDialog();
pageSetupDialog.PageSettings = new PageSettings();
pageSetupDialog.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A5", width: 583, height: 827);
pageSetupDialog.ShowDialog();
```

But after the dialog is shown, default PaperSize is Letter.

Is there any way to set the default paper size of `PageSetupDialog`?

Comment: That class changes the **print** settings, not the **printer** settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
     PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();

     IEnumerable<PaperSize> paperSizes = printerSettings.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>();

     PaperSize sizeA4 = paperSizes.First<PaperSize>(size => size.Kind == PaperKind.A4); // setting paper size to A4 size

     PageSetupDialog pageSetupDialog = new PageSetupDialog();

     pageSetupDialog.PageSettings = new PageSettings() { PaperSize = sizeA4 };
```

Comment: @Hussein Golshani your welcome. my friend do not write persian here. maybe other guys give you negative point. with the best regards.